# CSS animation working in Chrome/Edge, not FF

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I have a sprite that I've made and it works in Chrome but not Firefox [FF].

```
.hand {
width: 600px;
height: 529.5px;
margin: 2% auto;
background: url('hand2.png') center top;
animation: play 3s steps(24) infinite;
}

@keyframes play {
    100% { background-position: 0px -50840px; }

}
```

And then doing:

```
 <div class="hand"></div>
```

works in Chrome to show the animation. What does Firefox need from me? Thanks.

Comment: Looks like it should work in Firefox also. Can you upload the image and give us a link to it (or) create a demo?

Comment: Works in my Firefox without prefix tweaks -- http://i.imgur.com/rLAVNjk.png -- https://jsfiddle.net/qvvm57ac/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a little research ([CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/keyframe-animation-syntax/) and [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp)), and for browser support you need to specify the browsers with prefixes:

```
-moz-animation: ... //For FIREFOX

-webkit-animation: ... //For Safari and Chrome (Opera versions later than 15.0)

-o-animation: ... //For Opera versions lower than 15.0 and higher than 12.0
```

In the keyframes you also use the prefixes:

```
@-moz-keyframes *animation name* { ...

@-webkit-keyframes *animation name* { ...

@-o-keyframes *animation name* { ...
```

Also is a good idea to add the `animation:` and `@keyframes *animation name* {` without prefixes.

Hope this answer solve your problem.